# Windows 8.1 can't remove existing paired Bluetooth device nor connect new one

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, bluetooth, microsoft-surface

I have a surface pro 3 with windows 8.1 and currently installed microsoft sculpt touch mouse and creative inspire 2 sound system.

I have bought a new bluetooth microsoft sculpt mobile keyboard.
The keyboard is not recognized by my surface. It is recognized by a friend's surface.

Why ?

So I've tried to uninstall all my bluetooth devices and when I do so from the device manager, than remove them from bluetooth seetings, making sure ghost related devices are removed too, they still reappear, even if those devices are off.

Why ? How can I reset my entire bluetooth configuration ? How can I have my surface recognize my keyboard ?

(all simple solutions have been tested : rebooting, disconnecting, changing battery, put the devices close enough... and as I said, the keyboard is working fine on another surface which had no other bluetooth device)

EDIT :
I tried that too, without success, everything re-appears :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964685/how-do-i-totally-delete-reset-bluetooth-settings-in-windows-7

Comment: Did you try in Settings > PC and Devices > Manage BT devices ?

Comment: sure I did, it's not a simple one here ;)

Comment: Just another obvious question, but still have to ask, as it is not specified above: have you tried updating you bluetooth driver?

Comment: ahah, sure I did. Thanks for trying, in the meantime I found the solution, it was about the parameters of the bluetooth support service

Answer (score 14):

I was able to completely remove (and re-pair) a Bluetooth headset in Windows 10 that kept re-appearing despite trying to remove it using Bluetooth settings/devices and printers/device manager.

The paired Bluetooth devices seem to be permanently stored in the registry below the following branch:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices

Under this, you have one to several 12-digit device keys which represent the devices, like:

“00024c02b458” (which is a Bluetooth headset).

Use Registry Editor (regedit.exe) to delete the device key for the problem device and then reboot your computer; after this the paired device will be gone. You can find the correct device by double-clicking the “Name” value associated with each device, which shows the (binary!) device name in plain text.

You can also export the branch to a file for backup by right-clicking on the key and selecting “Export”.

Note: the error message I had in the event log was:

Event Id: 16/Source: BTHUSB: "The mutual authentication between the local Bluetooth adapter and a device with Bluetooth adapter address (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) failed.”

Comment: This solution worked when the top solution didn't.

Comment: This did not work for me; but another solution fixed it so wanted to suggest you try this as well:  when deleting hidden devices make sure you delete all the hidden ones under bluetooth, not just ones with your devices name in it.

Comment: @user28980 your solution worked for me!

Answer (score 13):

None of the suggested answers are simple or effective. There's a simple short video here (less than a minute) that actually is both. It took me all of five seconds to remove the device permanently (I was in Administrator mode--not sure if that makes a difference).  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsWtM6J7Dy8

1. Open the *Device Manager*
2. In the "View" option menu activate "Show hidden devices"
3. Look for the device in under "Bluetooth", right click and select uninstall

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please [edit your answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1320228/edit) to include information from the video- external links can disappear or change at any time. Thanks!

Comment: Tried not working

Comment: Yeah that didn't work for me either.

Comment: This was working wonderfully. After I removed several unused hidden devices, the stucked xbox controller was automatically removed from the bluetooth list and I was able to re-pair it normally.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to uninstall ALL the hidden Bluetooth devices; simply uninstalling the hidden one for the device I ultimately wanted to remove was not enough.

Comment: Spent hours on this. I also had to remove EVERY device that was hidden and greyed out and not just the xbox controller device...

Answer (score 12):

Wow, I finally found the solution.
It's crazy the time we can lose for such basic services.

From : http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/63589-63-cannot-remove-bluetooth-mouse-devices-window

> Go to START icon and type in services.msc and select services.
>
> The dialog box that opens has a long list of stuff but look for
>   BLUETOOTH SUPPORT SERVICE. Double click to open. Make sure it is
>   AUTOMATIC. Go to the LOG tab. Choose THIS ACCOUNT and type in LOCAL
>   SERVICE. A list of password (a 15-dot string) would appear. Delete all
>   the password in the PASSWORD and under CONFIRM. Choose Okay.
>
> It will ask you to restart the service. Once restarted, turn on your
>   bluetooth adaptor again. Put your mouse in pairing mode and add the
>   mouse. It works perfectly!!!

Comment: Why can't they ever make things easy. But that is good to know. I have a couple of Windows BT devices too. I especially like this keyboard with a trackpad ==> http://www.amazon.com/Motorola-Wireless-Keyboard-Trackpad-Packaging/dp/B006291K7A/ref=pd_sbs_op_3

Answer (score 1):

using win 8-1 32bit on a asus vivotab note 8. i had the same problem for 2 days and your solution did not solve it for me (bluetooth keyboard would always reappear) however:
 what did solve it was first disabling the keyboard in device-manager and second do a real restart shutdown /r via execute or command line... then when it restarts the keyboard would still be on the bluetooth list in the win8.1 metro bluetoothmanager but now it can be removed from the list and reconnected and work properly

kind regards
gspeet

Answer (score -1):

This fixed it for me:

1. Removed Bluetooth dongle.
2. Removed remanent device entry from Device Manager.
3. Open Administrative command prompt.
4. Execute command:

   ```
   sc delete bthport
   ```
5. Re-attached Bluetooth dongle, Windows automatically installed the driver.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. My pc now bluescreens on every restart. "DRIVER_UNLOADED_WITHOUT_CANCELLING_PENDING_OPERATIONS What failed:bthport.sys"